# How to get a list of keys from a record?

Tags: nushell

I have a record `{a:1, b:2}`.

I would like to know how to get list of keys from it, which would return `[a b]` in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{a:1, b:2} | columns
```

Not sure why I didn't notice `columns` initially.  I just retested on 0.69.1 which was out when this question was asked and it works the same as my original answer below.

In the latest release (0.74), the corresponding/converse `values` has been added as well.

---

*Old answer (still valid, but still non-optimal):*

It's been a few weeks since I've used Nushell, so there's probably a better way that I'm missing.  Quick (probably non-optimal) solution:

```
{a:1, b:2} | transpose | get column0
```